# Angular: using multiple proxy.config.js files when behind corporate proxy to access sandbox and production dynamically

Tags: angular, proxy

I work behind a corporate proxy, so we have to make use of the *proxy.config.js/proxyConfig* functionality outlined [here](https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy).

We have two backends that we're developing against, **Development** and **Production.** I've got my *proxy.config.js* file setup as stated in the link above, here's a sample:

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

var proxy = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY || 'http://proxy:6565';

var config = [
  {
    context: '/getThings',
    pathRewrite: { '^/getThings': '' },
    secure: false,
    target: 'https://endpoint/Development/getThings',
  },
  {
    context: '/getNames',
    pathRewrite: { '^/getNames': '' },
    secure: false,
    target: 'https://endpoint/Development/getMoreThings',
  },

...
```

As you can see, the `target` is specifically pointing to the **Development** environment here. What I'd like to do is to be able to setup the the proxy config in such a way that allows me to dynamically change to either **Development** or **Production** whenever the need requires. Right now, in order to do this, I would have to change all the `development` references to `production.`

I'm not sure if this can be done within the `proxy.config.js`; I thought you could configure multiple `serve` commands within `angular.json`, but it doesn't look this is possible neither. In fact, it looks like per command you are only given one way if setting up the proxy config [shown here](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxy-multiple-entries). Or if you can access the `environment.ts` file from within `proxy.config.js`.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks.
bengrah

Answer (score 1):

as simple solution you can indeed set up different proxy files for different serve configurations

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "proxyConfig": "proxy/proxy.prod.conf.js"
      },
      "development": {
        "proxyConfig": "proxy/proxy.dev.conf.js"
      }
   },
   ...
```

but i would suggest just reading the proxy option (or the whole proxy host) from the environmental variables

```
// proxy.conf.js
const host = process.env.PROXY_HOST
var config = [{
  ...
  target: `https://${host}/getThings`
}]
```

then either configure you IDE to run serve command with PROXY_HOST env variable set, or, if you like package.json scripts option, you could do something like this

```
  "serve:dev": "cross-env PROXY_HOST=endpoint/Development ng serve"
```

and don't forget to npm install cross-env

Comment: That's great - thank you @Andrei - I hadn't realised that you could add a `proxyConfig` per each `configuration` - I've modified my `angular.json` accordingly and it's all working how I would like it to now - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't realised that you could add a `proxyConfig` per each configuration - I've modified my `angular.json` so we're using different `build` configs which then pick up the appropriate `proxy.config.js` file.